# Use JQuery to bind mvvm data source

Tags: jquery, data-binding, kendo-ui, datasource

I have following:

```
<div class="container" data-bind="source: content" data-template="content-template"></div>
```

In JS, I want dynamically add more DIV's (better: clone the .container DIV) and change the data-bind source to content2, content3 ...

Basically I want this: `$(".question.clone2").data("source", content2)` ...

What is the correct syntax for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var clone = $('.container').first().clone();//clone first container div
  (clone).insertAfter('.container'); // inser clone after last container div
  var length = $('.container').length; // get how many container divs are there
  $('.container').last().attr('data-bind',"source: content"+length+""); //change last container div data-bind value (in autoincremeneted fashion like content2,content3,....)
});
```

```css
.container{
  float:left;
  width:40%;
  height:200px;
  background:grey;
  padding:10px;
  margin:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" data-bind="source: content" data-template="content-template"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var clone = $('.container').clone(); // use .first() if there are more then one .container class

$(clone).data("source", "content2");
```